# Audio Files Being Distorted in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in python and am using pygame. I put in a new audio file today and it sounds lower and slower than the original file. I have had this problem before, but changing the file type always fixed it. I have tried using this file in mp3, ogg, and wav formats, and the results are always the same. Does anyone know why this is or how I can fix it? I will attach my code below.

```
pygame.mixer.music.stop
pygame.mixer.music.load('Fantasy-World-Menu-2.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Comment: You have to provide more code for the reproducibility, giving such generic code does not help as it works as intended in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a number of parameters when initializing the mixer module:http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init It may help to play around with the frequency to change the pitch as you said it sounds "lower"

Comment: The problem is that this is the only sound file that is affected like this. All of the other sound files work fine. Wouldn't that solution change the sound of everything else?